# List[List[String]] in Scala

Tags: scala, list

We have a list of strings and i grouping them by below program.
input: `val k =     List("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a", "a", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e")`

output: `*List(List(a, a, a, a), List(b), List(c, c), List(a, a), List(d), List(e, e, e, e))*`

Program:

```
  def pack(ls:List[String]):List[List[String]]={

    val (a,next) = ls span {_ == ls.head}

    if ((next) == Nil) List(a)
    else a :: pack(next)

  }
```

However when i do a List cons operators, i get the output as mentioned below.

Input:

```
val a =List("a", "a", "a", "a")        
val b = List ("b")                     
val c = List ("c", "c" )               
val a1 = List("a", "a")                
val d = List("d")                      
val e = List( "e", "e", "e", "e")      

*List(a::b::c::a1::d::e)*
```

output:

```
*List(List(List(a, a, a, a), List(b), List(c, c), List(a, a), List(d), e, e, e, e))*
```

Is there any way i can the output as below in a single command in scala?

```
*List(List(a, a, a, a), List(b), List(c, c), List(a, a), List(d), List(e, e, e, e))*
```

Comment: I think the question is about the cons operator and how to make it mimic the result of the "grouping" function - and not about how to implement the grouping itself, so not sure it's actually a duplicate.

Comment: @TzachZohar yeah sorry, I was too quick in my judgment. Re-open

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> a::b::c::a1::d::List(e)
res0: List[List[String]] = List(List(a, a, a, a), List(b), List(c, c), List(a, a), List(d), List(e, e, e, e))
```

The cons operator prepends an item to a list - so construct a `List` around the last one if you want to then prepend all the other items one by one.

The easiest way to think about this is noticing the *types*:

- To construct a `List[List[String]]`, the cons operator expects to operate on an a `List[String]` on the left and a `List[List[String]]` on the right, to produce a new `List[List[String]]`: on the left should be an *item* in the resulting list, and on the right - a list with the same type as the expected result
- When you write `d::e`, you're doing `List[String] :: List[String]`, which already means you're not going to produce a `List[List[String]]` - so the right-hand side must be "wrapped" with a list to get the types right: `d::List(e)`
- Prepending the other items follows the same rule - prepending `List[String]`s to a `List[List[String]]`
- Once this is done - you get the expected result, without having to wrap the entire *result* with another list

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation, Now i really understand why List(a) in my program was needed and why List(e) has to be performed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to achieve the end result using `::`, adding a `Nil` at the end to the cons operation could yield the desired result.

```
a::b::c::a1::d::e::Nil
```

or you could wrap the last element in a `List` as @Tzach Zohar has mentioned.

```
a::b::c::a1::d::List(e)
```

Otherwise use

```
List(a,b,c,a1,d,e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you really want to use that syntax:

```
List(a::b::c::a1::d::e::Nil: _*)
```

You need the `: _*` at the end because otherwise you are passing a single element (of type List) to `List.apply()` and it is not interpreting it as a sequence, which is why you get `List[List[List]]` instead of the desired `List[List]`.